# Porque mi navegador web me da este error a la hora de ejecutar javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, google-chrome

Estaba haciendo un programa en JavaScript, todo iba bien hasta que comencé a notar que en mis logs algo no cuadraba, aunque el resultado en pantalla era el esperado, segui con mi codigo, más adelante intente hacer una función y en la consola otra vez no cuadraba lo que estaba probando.
Decidí llevar esa lógica a lo más fácil que pude en un archivo, para ver donde estaba mi error.

```
 let a = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        a[i] = {
            id: i
        }
    }

    console.log(a);

    for (let i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        a[5 - i] = {
            id:i
        }
    }

   console.log(a);
```

[Y este el resultado en consola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw1Nz.png)

Como pueden ver, en el primer log se esperaría que mostrara el id del 0 al 4 y en el segundo del 5 al 1. Sin embargo me muestra exactamente el  mismo resultado, que es el segundo log.

Pensé que tal vez me estaba olvidando de algún concepto de JavaScript así me fui a las devoloper tools a hacer una depuración paso por paso y sorprendentemente ahí si me mostraba el resultado esperado, también busque algún editor de código en línea y probé las mismas líneas y nuevamente me muestra el resultado esperado, el cual es el siguiente.

[Probando el codigo en un editor onlline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RX9kK.png)

Probé varios editores en línea y todos arrojaban el mismo resultado.
También probé el código en Node.js y el resultado es el esperado.
[Log en nodeJs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1NQ7.png)

Trate con distintos navegadores y reiniciando la máquina, también creando un nuevo archivo en una ubicación distinta, pero el resultado es el mismo y nefasto de la primera imagen.
En conclusión mi problema esta cuando se ejecuta el código en mi  navegador, cualquiera que sea.
Solo me falta probar en otra computadora a ver qué sucede, sin embargo no tengo otra pc por el momento.

¿Alguna idea de porque me sucede esto?

Es bastante frustrante, ya que así no puedo avanzar mucho.
¿Y como sé que es el único error que me está sucediendo?

Cualquier aporte muchas gracias.

Comment: Lee [ask]: pon un título que no suene a _clickbait_ ("este error": ¿cuál error?), y muestra los resultados en consola como texto, con formato, ya que [no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado y cuál es el obtenido?

Answer (score 2):

Lo cierto es que no es un error, sino un problema de cómo la consola del navegador gestiona las diferentes partes de el código.

Si pruebas a poner la primera mitad en la consola, ejecutas, y después cambias por la segunda y de nuevo ejecutas, verás que el error desaparece.

Sin embargo, la consola del navegador está realizando los dos `console.log(a)` a la vez al final del código.

De hecho, si quieres comprobar el código, te recomiendo que utilices siempre la herramienta debugger que ofrece Chrome. Si no conoces la herramienta, [aquí tienes un buen tutorial](https://es.javascript.info/debugging-chrome)

Comment: Hola, Moisés, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy útil sin duda, sabes como podría encontrar más información al respecto? Qué tema debería buscar en Google? O algún video que me recomiendes mirar? Me gustaría saber más de porque suceden estas cosas, ya que no debería ser normal y al ser la primera vez que me sucede me saco por completo de orbita. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Víctor Vasquez te lo acaba de explicar perfectamente en la otra respuesta. Un saludo!

Answer (score 2):

Esto sucede por la forma en la que funciona la consola del DevTools en Chrome.
Cuando expandes un objecto o array utiliza "Lazy Evaluation" para mostrar su contenido.

En el contexto de tu ejemplo, lo que llega a imprimirse en la consola no es el la variable "a" en si con sus valores, sino **una referencia** a la variable "a".

En el momento en que expandes "a" para ver sus valores, la consola del DevTools busca el valor de esa "referencia" y lo que encuentra son los ultimos valores de "a"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por tal motivo, en ambos casos te muestra los mismos valores.

Si quieres verificarlo por tu cuenta, puedes imprimir directamente los valores de la variable "a" con JSON.stringify

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

y obtendras el mismo output que los editores en linea o la consola de NodeJS.

De todas formas, hay un pequeño ícono de información en la consola del DevTools
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

con un mensaje de advertencia: "Este valor se evaluó en la primera expansión. Puede que haya cambiado desde entonces."

Encontré un buen artículo en Medium al respecto  (pero está en inglés )
https://medium.com/young-coder/why-chromes-developer-console-sometimes-lies-9487e45e91ae